# Is the tense of my sentence correct? "I __locked__ (lock) my house and went to my office.”

Tags: grammar, word-usage, past-tense

What will be the correct tense form of the verb in the sentence, "I _______ (lock) my house and went to my office."

I believe the answer should be locked. If it were had locked, the sentence would have been- I had locked my house and went to my office.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This is a very basic question, better suited to the English Language Learners forum.

Comment: Thank you Ma'am. However, my teacher claims that- When more than one action is in past tense, the last action should be in simple past and rest all should be in past perfect. So, should I stick with had locked now?

Comment: That is not necessarily true. If you are simply reporting a series of actions ('I got up, washed, shaved and had my breakfast') it's fine to use the simple past for them all. We use the past perfect if it is significant that the earlier action had finished. 'I had had breakfast and was ready to leave the house when the telephone rang.'

Comment: "I locked my house and went to my office."